# RecyclerVIew auto scroll to display all the elements as in News Feed etc.,

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

How to auto scroll `RecyclerView` smoothly so that user can see all the elements of the RecyclerView and scroll again from the start - as in News Feed etc.

I know `smoothScrollToPosition()` and `scrollToPosition()` but they would just end up scrolling too fast to the last element.

I want the RecyclerView to be animated and move slowly.

Comment: Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242968/android-horizontal-auto-scroll-in-recycler-view) with smooth scroll

Answer (score 27):

**Just to improve on the answer a little, it's auto scrolling infinity with smooth animation.**

```
final int speedScroll = 1200;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    int count = 0;
    boolean flag = true;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(count < adapter.getItemCount()){
            if(count==adapter.getItemCount()-1){
                flag = false;
            }else if(count == 0){
                flag = true;
            }
            if(flag) count++;
            else count--;

            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(count);
            handler.postDelayed(this,speedScroll);
        }
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(runnable,speedScroll);
```

This is exactly your answer but if you link to more smooth animation then use **LayoutManager**

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new CustomLinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Control you animation changing **MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH** value.

```
public class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
        final LinearSmoothScroller linearSmoothScroller =
                new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext()) {
                    private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 200f;

                    @Override
                    public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
                        return CustomLinearLayoutManager.this
                                .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel
                            (DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                        return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                    }
                };
        linearSmoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller);
    }
}
```

Comment: when I scroll manually. Auto scroll does not continue from that item.

Comment: Works perfectly but the slider time is too slow increasing to 3000 ms was perfect.

Comment: Running in my emulator, it seems that CPU is working hardly. I wonder if battery consumption would be too high.

Comment: OutOfMemoryError occured.

Comment: @AbhilashMaurya don't see any memory issue.

Answer (score 12):

I think this is the best solution for this.

```
    final int speedScroll = 150;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        int count = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(count < list.size()){
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(count++);
                handler.postDelayed(this,speedScroll);
            }


        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(runnable,speedScroll);
```

Comment: how to get the position of card displayed, and increment from it instead of starting again

Comment: This scroll is not smooth. And how to start again and again until activity is running ?

Comment: @AliAhmed true, its better to use the LayoutManager for scrolling other than the Recyclerview itself

Answer (score 9):

This is the best way to **Auto Scroll RecyclerView** and its **100%** working :

```
  RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_id);

  final int time = 4000; // it's the delay time for sliding between items in recyclerview

    final Adapter adapter = new Adapter(dataItems);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(rootView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    //The LinearSnapHelper will snap the center of the target child view to the center of the attached RecyclerView , it's optional if you want , you can use it
    final LinearSnapHelper linearSnapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
    linearSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView); 

    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() < (adapter.getItemCount() - 1)) {

                linearLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, new RecyclerView.State(), linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() + 1);
            }

            else if (linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == (adapter.getItemCount() - 1)) {

                linearLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, new RecyclerView.State(), 0);
            }
        }
    }, 0, time);
```

Comment: Really perfect answer. Thank you.

Comment: 100% good solution with smooth scroll

Answer (score 3):

**After Trial And Errors This Works Perfect For Me**

```
    final RecyclerView mRecyclerViewr;
    final ArrayList<String> stringArrayData = new ArrayList<String>
    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mRecyclerViewr.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), topPriceBarList);
    mRecyclerViewr.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        // Auto Scroll Left To Right
        final int scrollSpeed = 100;   // Scroll Speed in Milliseconds
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            int x = 15;        // Pixels To Move/Scroll
            boolean flag = true;
            // Find Scroll Position By Accessing RecyclerView's LinearLayout's Visible Item Position
            int scrollPosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();  
            int arraySize = stringArrayData.size();  // Gets RecyclerView's Adapter's Array Size

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (scrollPosition < arraySize) {
                    if (scrollPosition == arraySize - 1) {
                        flag = false;
                    } else if (scrollPosition <= 1) {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    if (!flag) {
                        try {
                            // Delay in Seconds So User Can Completely Read Till Last String
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); 
                            mRecyclerViewr.scrollToPosition(0);  // Jumps Back Scroll To Start Point
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    // Know The Last Visible Item
                    scrollPosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                    mRecyclerViewr.smoothScrollBy(x, 0);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, scrollSpeed);
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, scrollSpeed);
```

This Will Auto Scroll Your RecyclerView To The End, Wait For a Second *`(So User Can Read Till End)`* And **Jumps/Scroll Back To First String** In RecyclerView's Array List.
If You Want To Auto Scroll in Posetive And Negative direction `You Just Need To Change The Condition Instead Of Using if(!flag) You Need To Set Value Of x in it`

```
    if (flag) x = 15;
    else x= -15;  // For Auto Scroll To Negative i.e Left Direction
```

Comment: using smoothScrollBy disable onClick for items, how to fix that

Answer (score 2):

```
private void hanldeAutoScroll() {


    int position=0;

    final int duration = 2000;
    //final int pixelsToMove = 90;

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
     final Runnable SCROLLING_RUNNABLE = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            position++;

            if (position<urls.size())
            {
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);

            }else if (position==urls.size())
            {

                position=-1;

            }

           // recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(pixelsToMove, 0);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, duration);
        }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE, 2000);




}
```

Comment: Use smoothScrollToPosition rather than scrollToPosition for better scrolling like animation.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified in Kotlin:

```
 lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main, start = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT) {
        var position = MINIMUM_POSITION
        repeat(AUTO_SCROLL_REPEATING_TIMES) {
            delay(SCROLL_DELAY)
            rvBanners.smoothScrollToPosition(position)
            when {
                position+1 == listSize -> position = 0
                position == 0 -> position = MINIMUM_POSITION
                else -> position++
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want to start the auto-scroll at a specific time:

```
val job = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main, start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
        var position = MINIMUM_POSITION
        repeat(AUTO_SCROLL_REPEATING_TIMES) {
            delay(SCROLL_DELAY)
            rvBanners.smoothScrollToPosition(position)
            when {
                position+1 == listSize -> position = 0
                position == 0 -> position = MINIMUM_POSITION
                else -> position++
            }
        }
    }
...
job.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement it in this way, after setting recyclerview to adapter

```
final int duration = 10;
final int pixelsToMove = 263;
final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

final Runnable SCROLLING_RUNNABLE = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(pixelsToMove, 0);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, duration);
        }
    };

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            int lastItem = horizontalLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastItem == horizontalLayoutManager.getItemCount() - 1) {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE);
                Handler postHandler = new Handler();
                postHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        quickTips.setAdapter(null);
                        quickTips.setAdapter(adapter);
                        mHandler.postDelayed(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE, 2000);
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    });
    mHandler.postDelayed(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Smooth Auto Scrolling you can use this custom RecyclerView Class, where you can also set the scrolling time.

```
public class AutoScrollRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    private static long delayTime = 45;// How long after the interval to perform scrolling
    AutoPollTask autoPollTask;// Scroll thread
    private boolean running; // Is it rolling?
    private boolean canRun;// Can it be automatically scrolled, depending on whether the data exceeds the screen

    public AutoScrollRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AutoScrollRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        autoPollTask = new AutoPollTask(this);// Instantiate the scroll refresh thread
    }

    static class AutoPollTask implements Runnable {
        private final WeakReference<AutoScrollRecyclerView> mReference;

        // Use weak references to hold external class references to prevent memory leaks
        public AutoPollTask(AutoScrollRecyclerView reference) {
            this.mReference = new WeakReference<>(reference);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            AutoScrollRecyclerView recyclerView = mReference.get();// Get the recyclerview object
            if (recyclerView != null && recyclerView.running && recyclerView.canRun) {
                recyclerView.scrollBy(2, 2);// Note the difference between scrollBy and scrollTo
                //delayed to send
                recyclerView.postDelayed(recyclerView.autoPollTask, delayTime);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                /*if (running)
                    stop();*/
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                /*if (canRun)
                    start();*/
                break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(e);
    }

    //Open: If it is running, stop first -> then open
    public void start() {
        if (running)
            stop();
        canRun = true;
        running = true;
        postDelayed(autoPollTask, delayTime);
    }
    
    public void stop() {
        running = false;
        removeCallbacks(autoPollTask);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Answer is Aware Of Activity/Fragment Lifecycle and this is important
below answer is used by taking notes of other answres:**

> **Using Kotlin:**

```
private lateinit var layoutManager:LinearLayoutManager

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    layoutManager =  LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)

    binding.autoScrollingRecyclerViewId.layoutManager = layoutManager 

    runSlideShow() // <= auto sliding effect function

    return binding.root
}
```

**> Slide Show Effect:**

```
private fun runSlideShow(){
    
    lifecycleScope.launch {

        while(isActive) {

            if (layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() < (restaurantsAdapter?.itemCount ?:0)  - 1)
             {
                layoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(
                    binding.autoScrollingRecyclerViewId,
                    RecyclerView.State(),
                    layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() + 1
                )
            } else if (layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == (restaurantsAdapter?.itemCount ?:0) - 1) {
                layoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(
                    binding.autoScrollingRecyclerViewId,
                    RecyclerView.State(),
                    0
                )
            }
            delay(6000)
        }
    }
}
```