# Horizontally auto Recycler view in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can we create horizontal recycler view in android.

```
 private fun handleScroll(
        layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager,
        homeItemViewHolder: HomeItemViewHolder?, position: Int
    ) {
        homeItemViewHolder?.rcvHomeItems?.addOnScrollListener(object :
            RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                rcvrecyclerView = recyclerView
                val lastItem: Int = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
                val firstItem: Int = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                Log.i("firstItem", firstItem.toString())

                if (lastItem != -1) {
                    if (lastItem == layoutManager.itemCount - 1) {
                        Log.d("lastItem", lastItem.toString())
                        Log.d("lastItem2", (layoutManager.itemCount - 1).toString())
                        Log.d("position", position.toString())

                        mHandler.removeCallbacks(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE)
                        val postHandler = Handler()
                        postHandler.postDelayed({
                            recyclerView.adapter = null
                            notifyItemChanged(position)
                            //recyclerView.adapter = catHomeAdapter
                            mHandler.postDelayed(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE, 14000)
                        }, 14000)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        mHandler.postDelayed(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE, 14000)
    }
```

I have Try this but there comes the different problem in auto slider. Sometime the slider get faster unusual.
Can AnyOne Provide best way to make recycler view auto slide. Thanks in advance

Comment: check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805031/auto-scroll-recyclerview-slider

Answer (score 0):

Give direction as horizonatl while creating LinearLayoutmManager object as below.

```
new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true)
```