# Android Horizontal Auto scroll in Recycler view

Tags: android

I have two values in list and displaying that in horizontal list view using Recycler view. Here I need to auto scroll the horizontal list unlimited.
I tried with the below code but no result.

[HorizontalScrollView: auto-scroll to end when new Views are added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720469/horizontalscrollview-auto-scroll-to-end-when-new-views-are-added)

Comment: This answer can be helpful and its 100% working : [Auto Scroll RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56872365/6842344)

Answer (score 18):

please check the solution here.
https://github.com/ritesh-bhavsar86/StockAutoScroll

> first create runnable:

```
final int duration = 10;
final int pixelsToMove = 30;
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private final Runnable SCROLLING_RUNNABLE = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        rv_autoScroll.smoothScrollBy(pixelsToMove, 0);
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, duration);
    }
};
```

> then after setadapter() to the recyclerView use following:

```
rv_autoScroll.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            int lastItem = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if(lastItem == layoutManager.getItemCount()-1){
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE);
                Handler postHandler = new Handler();
                postHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        rv_autoScroll.setAdapter(null);
                        rv_autoScroll.setAdapter(madapter);
                        mHandler.postDelayed(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE, 2000);
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    });
    mHandler.postDelayed(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE, 2000);
```

rv_autoScroll is recyclerview

and

layoutmanager is LayoutManager which set to recyclerview

Comment: Thank you... its working perfect... But I cant set clickListener... Help me with that...

Comment: i guess..you can set click listener like we set in adapter..check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44152237/7790252

Comment: I have set the click listener, but when the scrolling starts onClickListener is not working...

Comment: @Simon have you found any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
trainigItemRV.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                int lastItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if(lastItem == linearLayoutManager.getItemCount()-1){
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE);
                    Handler postHandler = new Handler();
                    postHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            trainigItemRV.setAdapter(null);
                            trainigItemRV.setAdapter(productsTrainingItemAdapter);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE, 2000);
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }
        });
        mHandler.postDelayed(SCROLLING_RUNNABLE, 2000);

This Works For me..
```