# Recycler view Click Listener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener

I'm working in the application of Android approached to finish it but I found the problem in recyclerView, and i didn't know how to implement a click listener on the textview of an Item of the recyclerView ? (when i click in the item)

I have a multiselect recyclerview...only when i select the recyclerview item,the textview becomes vissible

Comment: this link might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/24471410/8164071

Comment: nope...didnt work @PriteshVadhiya

Comment: try it like this one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151979/how-to-add-onclick-listener-to-recycler-view

Comment: the single click is deselecting my selection..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here use this:

My recyclerView row has 2 textViews :

```
 public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView name,price;

        public MyViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            price= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);

            name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("Test","Name clicked : "+getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });


        }
    }
```

from this position you can get the value of particular item using your dataList.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: My recycler view is a multiselect recycler view...ie)when i long press the current view item get selected....only now the text view is vissible...I tried your code its deselecting the item due to the GestureDetector ..What to do

Comment: do you have any function on single tap of recyclerview row??

Comment: Ya..i have a funtion..it opens another activity

Comment: I have just tested the functionality it's detecting both the clicks on the particular textView and the complete recyclerView row. Can you share your code where you have implemented the functionality??

Comment: ok let me know if I understood your problem correctly. what you want is on singletap on recylerView row you're going to a new activity but if you long press on the row a textview will be visible and on tap of that textview you want to have some other function not the normal switching of the activity.

Comment: no..not exactly..when i longpress on the item,the item gets highlighted and mentee ,mentor textview gets vissible ...now i want to click on mentee or mentor to do some corresponding function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149578/discussion-between-sumit-and-anitha-sundaramurthy).

Answer (score 0):

Implement View.OnClickListener on the textView in the recycler adapter.

Comment: set the TextView as clickable too

Comment: didnt work,,thats why asked as a question in the first place

Comment: Try using onClickListener on the textView in the adapter instead of OnItemTouch in the Activity

Comment: My recycler view is a multiselect recycler view...ie)when i long press the current view item get selected....only now the text view is vissible...I tried your code its deselecting the item due to the GestureDetector ..What to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use adapter and from adapter you can give click listener for particular component(i.e., TextView) .

Comment: My recycler view is a multiselect recycler view...ie)when i long press the current view item get selected....only now the text view is vissible...I tried your code its deselecting the item due to the GestureDetector ..What to do

Answer (score 0):

this might help you....

```
 public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{


        TextView textview;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

                textview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           textview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
             //do your actions here

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I have solution to your problem:

First of all , in your RecyclerView's  item layout , make the parent layout clickable and your TextView's visibility as gone:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_layout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/text_title"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="50dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Making your parent layout clickable is necessary, and declare this LinearLayout in your ViewHolder class as well like this:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 private LinearLayout itemLayout;
 private TextView textItem;
 ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
 super(itemView);
 itemLayout=(LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_item);
 textItem=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
}
```

Then instead of itemView.setOnClickListener, use itemLayout.setOnClickListener()
as below:

```
itemlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
      //make your textView or your items Visible 
      //make your textview clickable
      //set Your itemLayoutClickable as false

    }
            });
```

Then finally, make onClickListener for your TextView:

```
textItem.setOnClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

//perform your text click action
}
});
```

For making the TextView Invisible again, you might wanna add some extra logic, such as setting flag , checking flag and making the items visible or invisible and notifying the adapter