# Pass the data from Recyclerview adapter to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

In my fragment class

```
    public class ReceiveFragment extends Fragment implements ReceiverRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClick {

btnGenAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                    linearLayoutMyWalletInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    linearLayoutGenAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                recyclerViewAdapter = new ReceiverRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),subjects, emails,this);

                recyclerViewCardContainer.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);



            }
        });

@Override
    public void onClick(String value) {

    }
```

and in the ReceiverRecyclerViewAdapter class i have create one interface and now when i write in the fragment  **recyclerViewAdapter = new ReceiverRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),subjects, emails,this);
}**  it gives the complie time error when i use **"this"** parameter.

and my ReceiverRecyclerViewAdapter class

```
    public class ReceiverRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReceiverRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{
     private OnItemClick mCallback;


    public ReceiverRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context1,String[] SubjectValues1, String[] SubjectValues2,OnItemClick listener){

            SubjectValues = SubjectValues1;
            EmailValues2 = SubjectValues2;

            context = context1;
            this.mCallback = listener;
        }

  public interface OnItemClick {
        void onClick(String value);
    }

  itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // get position
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();

                    // check if item still exists
                    if(pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        String clickedDataItem = SubjectValues[pos];
                       Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You clicked " + clickedDataItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mCallback.onClick(clickedDataItem);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: bind OnClickListener  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151979/how-to-add-onclick-listener-to-recycler-view

Comment: Try my answer..Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing 4 parameters from the fragment but your constructor is expecting 3. So you need to add `Context` as your first parameter in the adapter.

UPDATE:

You are passing `this` instance inside an anonymous class which is `OnClickListener` which does not implement the interface. So instead of this, pass `ReceiveFragment.this`, this way you are referencing your fragment which implements the interface:

```
recyclerViewAdapter = new ReceiverRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),subjects, emails, ReceiveFragment.this);
```

Comment: i have edited the code, In the original code i am passing and receive the 4 parameter. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because when you pass `this` from OnClickListener, it is passing an instance of on click and not that interface. 
You can initialize your interface in your fragment like below code and pass that in the adapter.

```
OnItemClick onitemClick = (OnItemClick) this;

btnGenAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                linearLayoutMyWalletInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                linearLayoutGenAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            recyclerViewAdapter = new ReceiverRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),subjects, emails,onitemClick);

            recyclerViewCardContainer.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        }
    });


 public class ReceiverRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReceiverRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

   private OnItemClick mCallback;

    public ReceiverRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, String[] SubjectValues1, String[] SubjectValues2,OnItemClick listener){

        SubjectValues = SubjectValues1;
        EmailValues2 = SubjectValues2;

        this.context = context;
        this.mCallback = listener;
    } 

 public interface OnItemClick {
        void onClick(String value);
    }

  itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // get position
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();

                    // check if item still exists
                    if(pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        String clickedDataItem = SubjectValues[pos];
                       Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You clicked " + clickedDataItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mCallback.onClick(clickedDataItem);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: @Raghunandan try it, he will definately got this issue.

Comment: you should look at the other answer by riadrifai and also the code in the question closely

Comment: if you will pass this from onclick, do you think it will pass interface instance? You even can try with creating demo man.

Comment: that's a difference issue cause this does not refer to Fragment but the params passed to constructor is 4 while the constructor has 3 params actually

Comment: I already have sort out both issue in my answer. Please look it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**In adapter :**

Write `public ReceiverRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context1,String[] SubjectValues1, String[] SubjectValues2,OnItemClick listener)`

**In fragment :**

1. Make a object : `OnItemClick onItemClick;`
2. In constructor : `this.OnItemClick = onItemClick;`
3. Pass this object in adapter.

**In activity :**

Implement this `listner`.

Comment: noting to do with the issue op is facing `ReceiverRecyclerViewAdapter(String[] SubjectValues1, String[] SubjectValues2,OnItemClick listener)` The constructor has 3 params but while passing you have 4 `(getActivity(),subjects, emails,this);`

Comment: @Raghunandan Before down vote please check the answer. It will work perfect