# How to get Recyclerview id with findViewById from a void method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-context

I'm trying to click a recyclerview item and get the clicked item's data.

In this time, i want to use a method to query a database and show the data in recyclerview.

I'm facing with a problem while method run. Method can't find RecyclerView at R.id becuse of context, i guess.

Here is my code that i try, method is in MainActivity but not in onCreate method sure.

While debugging, it stops at the first line of below code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ...


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


mRcyView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
  ...

}
 public void sqlQuery  (String param) {

    **mRcyView = (RecyclerView)this.findViewById(R.id.rv);**
    mdbHelper = new DB_Helper(this);
    mRows = new ArrayList<>();
    mRows = mdbHelper.getListRow2(param);
    mRvAdapter = new RV_Adapter(this,mRows);
    mRcyView.setAdapter(mRvAdapter);
}
}
```

When disable the findViewById row, query works and get a value mRows. However Recyclerview set adapter does not work.

Here is the method first call and RecyclerView adapter code

```
public class RV_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RV_Adapter.ViewHolder> {




public RV_Adapter(Context rContext, List<EachRow> rows) {

    this.rows = rows;
    this.rContext = rContext;
}




public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

   ...

    public ViewHolder(View v, final Context context) {

        super(v);

        this.context = context;
        ...


        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                EachRow eachRow = rows.get(pos);
                String kSenArab = eachRow.getkSenArab();

                MainActivity act = new MainActivity();
                act.sqlQuery(kSenArab);


            }
        });


    }

}
```

}

Here is the error logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:56)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
    at com.mustafa.otre.MainActivity.sqlQuery(MainActivity.java:112)
    at com.mustafa.otre.RV_Adapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(RV_Adapter.java:116)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5609)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22259)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

This is not only null exception question. it contains context reach problem

Thanks for replies.

Comment: In which class is this method in ?

Comment: mainactivity class

Comment: can you update your question with code where you call this method?

Comment: is this enough?

Comment: it still doesn't mention where `sqlQuery` is called and where you have declared the `RecyclerView`

Comment: i updated. sqlQuery called from RV_Adapter. RecyclerView declared first onCreate method. Shall i declare it in sqlQuery too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 MainActivity act = new MainActivity();
 act.sqlQuery(kSenArab);
```

You should not try to initialize `MainActivity` in this manner. The reason you are facing the error is due to above attempt.

Try not reference `MainActivity` from your ViewHolder. If you want to handle the onClick in MainActivity then implement an interface as indicated in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151979/how-to-add-onclick-listener-to-recycler-view).

Comment: thank you. i change the structure and i use interface to pass a value one class to activity.

Answer (score 1):

Here :

```
MainActivity act = new MainActivity();
 act.sqlQuery(kSenArab);
```

Not right way to access methods from Activity which required Context.

Do it as using Context parameter passed in `RV_Adapter` :

```
( (MainActivity) rContext).sqlQuery(kSenArab);
```

And best way is create a listener using `interface` for updating Activity from Adapter.