# One timer, multiple intents

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an app, where you have multiple cardviews on when you click on them it shows you a intro then after 10 seconds redirects to you to the activity, but i only know how to do one, but with multiple activities idk how to do that.

heres de code

```
   TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("param"));


    Animation myamin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.transition);
    textView.startAnimation(myamin);


    final Intent a = new Intent(this, phonensmar.class);

    Thread timer = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                sleep(3000);
            }catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {

                startActivity(a);

                finish();


            }
        }
    };

    timer.start();
```

Comment: Use recyclerview with onClick listener for items, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44152237

Comment: I don't understand your question.