# How can i fix my problem with RecyclerView and OnClickAdapter?

Tags: android, listener, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Sorry, i have a problem, i have created ad adapter for a recyclerView to click on one of my item but it doesn't work, it is very frustrating, do you have any ideas?
I have used it in a old application and it works properly but now i don't know why it doesn't work...
Here is my adapter:

```
public class TecniciAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TecniciAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Utenti> tecniciList;
private OnTecniciListner onTecniciListner;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    public TextView nome;
    public TextView cognome;
    public TextView stato;
    public OnTecniciListner onTecniciListner;


    public MyViewHolder(View view, OnTecniciListner onTecniciListner) {
        super(view);
        nome = view.findViewById(R.id.textNome);
        cognome = view.findViewById(R.id.textCognome);
        stato = view.findViewById(R.id.textCurrentState);
        this.onTecniciListner = onTecniciListner;
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onTecniciListner.onTecniciClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

public TecniciAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Utenti> list, OnTecniciListner onTecniciListner) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.tecniciList = list;
    this.onTecniciListner = onTecniciListner;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public TecniciAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            .inflate(R.layout.technician_item, viewGroup, false);

    return new TecniciAdapter.MyViewHolder(view, onTecniciListner);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
    myViewHolder.nome.setText(tecniciList.get(i).getNome());
    myViewHolder.cognome.setText(tecniciList.get(i).getCognome());
    myViewHolder.stato.setText(tecniciList.get(i).getStato());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tecniciList.size();
}

public interface OnTecniciListner{
    void onTecniciClick(int position);
}
```

}

and this is the part in the fragment:

```
TecniciAdapter adapter = new TecniciAdapter(getActivity(), tecniciList, TecniciFragment.this);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have also this in my fragment:

```
    @Override
public void onTecniciClick(int position) {
    Utenti tecnici = tecniciList.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Onclick listener to recycler view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151979/how-to-add-onclick-listener-to-recycler-view)

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, describe what the exact observed behavior is and what the expected behavior should be. For UI issues, a screenshot or video is usually helpful. Include the exact wording of any error messages (including the full [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174) of any exception, if applicable, as well as which line of code is producing it). Please see [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: it isn't a error, if i click on item of RecyclerView, it doesn't do anything, i have altro tried to show a toast in my onTecniciClick but it doesn't do anything, it is like that i have never touch the item

Comment: @pazz98 answer by oussama-zaoui should work if you are ok with getting rid of your listener

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create an instance of `OnTecniciListner` in your `ViewHolder` class, the one in the `TecniciAdapter` should work just fine.

So your `MyViewHolder` class should look like this

```java
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    public TextView nome;
    public TextView cognome;
    public TextView stato;


    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        nome = view.findViewById(R.id.textNome);
        cognome = view.findViewById(R.id.textCognome);
        stato = view.findViewById(R.id.textCurrentState);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onTecniciListner.onTecniciClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work anyway, it seems that i never touch any item also with this

Answer (score 0):

in `onBindViewHolder`try this :

```
myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```